# Call xml2json from react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call xml2json from react. I tried this code http://plnkr.co/edit/ETYguAH2ZS3ePkiGndyD?p=preview. I basically want to call the getVersion function from the xml2json file. I know I am doing something wrong, and I won't pretend I know what I'm doing. So which is the right way?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="xml2json.js"></script>
```

```
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx">
  var Card = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
      var component = this;
      $.get("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml", function(data){
        component.setState(data);
      })
    }, 
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          ...
          <h3>{this.getVersion()}</h3>
          <hr/>
        </div>
      );
    } 
  });

  var Main = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
            <Card login="andreicvasniuc27"/>
        </div>
      )
    }
  })

  React.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your render function should look more like this. In xm2json.js you declare a global variable `var x2js = new X2JS();`. You can access this object and its methods from your render function.

```
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          ...
          <h3>{x2js.getVersion()}</h3>
          <hr/>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/B70pQakkRCkzvGty7PLh?p=preview